# pip mechanism of ```pip install ".[source-pt]"```

Tags: python, pip

[deepdoctection](https://pypi.org/project/deepdoctection/0.15/) PyPi has the pip installation description:

```
cd deepdoctection
pip install ".[source-pt]"
```

[deepdoctection](https://github.com/deepdoctection/deepdoctection) github does not have `source-pt` in the root.

Help understand which options or mechanism of [pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/) is used here and what is `source-pt`?